# Wordpress force user to login by clicking on a link which refers to public post

Tags: php, wordpress

If a user clicks on a link on my index.php and they are not logged in, they should be redirected to /register.. The links refers to a public post which is accesible without login, though. So it is not an option to check it in the single post page itself.

How can i do that? I am just not getting the right idea..

thank you

Comment: May I know the logic behind asking users to login when the post is available publicly?

Comment: I want to boost the amount of user accounts

Answer (score 0):

Basically the logic should be something like this:

```
   <?php 
   // If not logged, then display WordPress login form

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    $args = array(
        'form_id' => 'loginform',
        'label_username' => __( 'Username: ' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'Password: ' ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me ' ),
        'label_log_in' => __( ' Log In ' ),
        'remember' => true,
        'value_username' => NULL,
        'value_remember' => false
    );
    wp_login_form( $args );
} 
// If user is already user logged in, then show other stuff or redirect
else { 

   //Do some redirection or display link
   echo '<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">Link</a>';


  }

  ?>
```

Comment: the point is, I just want to show the signup form when a user clicks on a link, the user should be able to see the index.php site. But has to login if he wants so see the posts. But the posts should be public :D tricky stuff

Comment: It sounds like you need a JavaScript solution that displays a popup/login form onClick on _any_ link?